# Finding a specific partitioning of a finite ordered set of positive integers.

Tags: optimization, order-theory, constraints, set-partition

**Definition of partitioning**

Let $S$ be a finite ordered set of positive integers.
$$S = \{s_i \mid s_i \in \Bbb{Z}^+\}$$

E.g. $S = \{4, 7, 9, 8, 3, 2, 5\}$

Given this set $S$, we define $P$ as a partition of set $S$ such that:

1. $P = \{p_1, p_2, p_3, \ldots, p_k\}$.
2. $p_j$ (for some $j$) is either a singleton set or if $s_l, s_m \in p_j $ and if $l < m$, then $s_i \in p_j\ \forall i \in (l,m)$.
3. Given $p_j = \{s_i \mid l\leq i\leq m\}$, we define function $f^-$ on $p_j$ as

$$f^-(p_j) =
\begin{cases}
s_i,  & \text{if $p_j$ is a singleton} \\
\sum_{i=l}^{m-1} |s_{i+1} - s_i|, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

**Problem**

Given a set $S$, find a $P$ such that,

1. $\sum f^-(p_j), \forall p_j \in P$ is minimized and,
2. $\max(|p_j|), \forall p_j \in P$ is minimized (where $|p_i|$ represents the cardinality of set $p_j$)

**Example:**

Let $S = \{1, 2, 8\}$, one partitioning of this set could be $P = \{\{1\}, \{2, 8\}\}$. You can verify easily that $P$ is passing the two constraints defined above.

Comment: Shouldn't (2) be minimized by taking all singletons?

Comment: For (1), notice that if P has a singleton set, then merging the singleton with one of its neighbors improves your score because it replaces $s$ with $|s-t|$ in the sum. So an optimal set has no singletons. The problem reduces to starting with $P=\{S\}$ and placing your "dividers" to maximize the sum of the cross-divider differences (since these are excluded from the sum) while avoiding creating singletons. Does a greedy algorithm work?

Comment: @Karl exactly! you can achieve (2) by taking all singletons. However, I need to achieve both (1) and (2) i.e., minimizing the summation as well as the cardinality of the maximum set. I'm not sure if a greedy approach can help since there are two constraints. Should I use linear programming?

Comment: Hmm, how do you know a P exists that simultaneously minimizes both (1) and (2)?

Comment: Yeah, it might be the case that such P may not even exist, in such case a near  optimal solution (which minimises the summation of above two condition) may suffice.